# Anything in addition to a href link in a page?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, browser, href

https://www.harriscountylawlibrary.org/remote-database-access

I am trying to directly type the link below (which is under an "westlaw" image in the above webpage) in a browser address bar to visit it. But it shows "An error occurred, please try again."

https://westlawpatronaccess.thomsonreuters.com/remote/RPA-000713276-4200

However, if I click the Westlaw image directly, I can visit the resulted webpage correctly. What is done in the page so that one has to click the "Westlaw" image to access the link?

How to access the resulting webpage with a direct link?

Comment: The reason this question is a poor fit for the site is that the thing to look at is on a third-party website that is liable to change in the future. Readers will go easy on a new contributor who doesn't know this rule, but they are probably minded to downvote a 10K user who absolutely should know.

Comment: As an aside, all of your questions are written in a form that suggests you would like readers to take a project off your hands and do it for you ("does anyone know", "could someone tell me", etc). If you get into the habit of using "How can I" then readers will know you are willing to do the bulk of the work. It's a small change, but it reflects an engineering mindset.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably checking the [`Referer` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer)

```bash
curl -iL -e 'https://www.harriscountylawlibrary.org' https://westlawpatronaccess.thomsonreuters.com/remote/RPA-000713276-4200
```

Comment: How did you verify that this is what happened when one click the image? The curl output is not the same as the the browser output. So I can not verify whether this is the true cause.

Comment: @user1424739 I tried a Chrome extension ([Referer Control](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/referer-control/hnkcfpcejkafcihlgbojoidoihckciin?hl=en)) that forces referer headers, and results indicate that the page can be accessed manually using the expected referer URL.

Comment: @user1424739 I compared the output with and without the header. Since they were different, I guessed that that's was it's doing.

Comment: How the header is added to the request? I don't see anything on the webpage requiring the header to be added to the request. Can you tell where the requirement is written on the webpage?

Comment: @user1424739 The header is added to the request with `-e`. `curl -e <ref-header-value> …`. https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-e. 

The requirement is not on the webpage, it's server-side logic.

Comment: I don't under what do you mean server side logic. The request is sent by the browser, which is by definition clientside. The question is how the browser know to add the Referrer field on the request? Is the browser always add the Referer field in all HTTP requests?